# Ideal island for bareboat sailing in Caribbean?

Tags: caribbean, sailing, charter

My boyfriend and I are planning a sailing trip to the Caribbean over Thanksgiving week this year. We have already been sailing in the British Virgin Islands and really enjoyed it, but want to go somewhere new this time.

We're both experienced sailors and would like to charter bareboat. Are there other islands in the Caribbean that are ideal for pleasure sailing (safe anchorages, interesting scenery etc), but also have a broad range of yacht charters available from reputable companies? We're looking for a single keel 34'-41' yacht.